# Connect to carrier directly using sim information without actual simcard

Tags: sim-card

Are there anyway to copy sim card into Android and save the sim information, then use that information to connect to cell towers without having an actual sim card in my phone.

Are there any app out there that can do this ? 
a virtual sim card app ?

Comment: There's [eSIM (embedded SIM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESIM), but I don't think that's what you want...

Comment: Actually back in 2007-08 and before I used to copy multiple SIM cards to a multi-SIM, when dual SIM phones were not very common. But then the SIMs got more secure. SIM as well eSIM is a Secure Element chip which runs code inside it and provides only the information (after authentication) it's designed for. iSIM - a part of SoC - also makes use of hardware root of trust, so is even more secure by design. Dumping whole software out isn't the intended behavior, but hacks do exist. Though probability is extremely low. It's out of the scope of apps. You need some serious low level hacking skills.